# Qtranslate and W3 Total Cache cookie redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, w3-total-cache, qtranslate-x

I have the following issue:

- I have qtranslate with 2 languages (en - main/root, bg - secondary;
- I have a cookie set in my browser for the second language (qtrans_front_language);
- When I have not activated Late Initialization in Page Cache the website works extremely fast, but always serves root, so the qtranslate redirect doesn't work;
- Correct redirection works only with Late Initialization active, but that affects the response time.

I have read a lot of articles, but nothing helps, I was thinking if there is a way that I can set all the plugins that require cookies read be executed before the cached page serve.

That is a common issue, let's discuss it and come up with some solution the developers of the plugins can use.

P.S: same issue with WP Super Cache as well.